# Get All Attributes of an XML File Using XPath in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, sax

I am parsing a complex XML file and I want to get ALL of the attributes and its values from the entire document using preferably XPath in Java. The problem is the document contains many nested tags within the structure of the tree so it is difficult. If there is another easier way to do this in Java that will be helpful as well. I tried DOM already but the multiple nesting makes it difficult with this approach.

**As an example if I have this:**

```
<bookstore>
 <book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
 </book>
 <book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
 </book>
 <book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
 </book>
 <book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
 </book>
</bookstore>
```

**I want this:**

```
category : COOKING
lang : en
category : CHILDREN
lang : en
category : WEB
lang : en
category : WEB
lang : en
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the nested structure (i.e. you just want a list of the attributes), it is straightforward to use [SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html).

For example, you can subclass `DefaultHandler`, overriding the `startElement` method to gather the `Attributes` from every tag:

```
class GetAttributesHandler extends DefaultHandler {
  List<Attributes> attributes = new ArrayList<>();

  @Override
  public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) {
    this.attributes.add(attributes);
  }
}
```